# I am unable to understand the execution of following mathematical equation using JavasScript

Tags: javascript, math, three.js

I am unable to understand this line of code `this.position = convertlatlonToVec3(cardinal.lat, cardinal.lon).multiplyScalar(radius);` used in function labelBox. How does multiplyScalar(radius) works.

```
function convertlatlonToVec3(lat, lon)
{
  var cosLat = Math.cos(circle.getCenter().lat() * degrees);
  var sinLat = Math.sin(circle.getCenter().lat() * degrees); 

  var xSphere = radiusEquator * cosLat;
  var ySphere = 0;
  var zSphere = radiusPoles * sinLat;
  var rSphere = Math.sqrt(xSphere*xSphere + ySphere*ySphere + zSphere*zSphere);

  var tmp = rSphere * Math.cos(lat * degrees);    

  xSphere = tmp * Math.cos((lon - circle.getCenter().lng()) * degrees);
  ySphere = tmp * Math.sin((lon - circle.getCenter().lng()) * degrees);
  zSphere = rSphere * Math.sin(lat * degrees);

  var x = -ySphere/circle.getRadius();
  var y = (zSphere*cosLat - xSphere*sinLat)/circle.getRadius();
  var z = 0;

  return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);

}

function labelBox(cardinal, radius, root)
{
  this.screenvector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
  this.labelID = 'MovingLabel'+ cardinal.ID;
  this.position = convertlatlonToVec3(cardinal.lat, cardinal.lon).multiplyScalar(radius);
}
```

Comment: `convertlatlonToVec3` returns `new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z)` ... this probably has a method called `multiplyScalar` - which is subsequently executed

Comment: @Jaromanda X I need to know how does multiplyScalar(radius) works.

Comment: so now you've changed the question - have you looked at three.js documentation?

Comment: @Jaromanda X ya i looked into three.js document but couldn't find about multiplyScalar(radius).

Comment: I found it by searching for `three.js Vector3 multiplyScalar` - first result in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js documentation **[here](https://threejs.org/docs/)**
For `THREE.Vector3` `multiplyScalar` method look docs are **[here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3.multiplyScalar)**:

> **.multiplyScalar ( s ) this**
>   Multiplies this vector by scalar s.

Contents of this method can be found [in the `THREE.Vector3` class](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Vector3.js#L215-L233) and look like this:

```
multiplyScalar: function ( scalar ) {

    if ( isFinite( scalar ) ) {

        this.x *= scalar;
        this.y *= scalar;
        this.z *= scalar;

    } else {

        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.z = 0;

    }

    return this;

},
```